# communication between iphone and windows pc

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, adb

the company I work for wants to replicate certain performances on Apple devices. I would need to make an iphone communicate with a windows pc in the same way that ADB communicates with android devices (logcat, install, etc, etc). Is there an equivalent to ADB in the iOS world working on windows or ubuntu shell?

Comment: Best you can get on a non-jailbroken device are the `libimobiledevice` tools. The are also available for Windows but getting a pre-compiled package is not that easy. For Linux and MacOS using libimobiledevice is much easier (clone the git repos, compile and use it, other packages are often too old).

Comment: any suggestions in case of Jailbroken device?

Comment: Activate openssh on a jailbroken phone. Forward the ssh port via iproxy through USB to the connected PC